# Can the input parameter to a C++ function be of variable type?

Tags: c++, types

Is is possible to create a C++ function with an input parameter of an undefined type, or with a pre-defined list of accepted types?

For example, I have a C++ class with several variables of different types. The variables are updated from real-world data and I want to update each variable as the data arrives.

The (inelegant) pseudo code for such a function would look like this:

```
void objectFiller (myObject, input_var)
{
  if (typeid(input_var).name() == "int") 
  {
    myObject.int_var = input_var;
  }

  if (typeid(input_var).name() == "double")
  {
    myObject.double_var = input_var;
  }

  if (typeid(input_var).name() == "string")
  {
    myObject.string_var = input_var;
  }
}
```

Where the type of `input_var` is either unknown, or is from a pre-determined list of acceptable types.

Now, I understand that because C++ is statically typed, the answer to this question is probably no. And I understand that I could achieve the above with three individually tailored functions. However I still wanted to ask the question in case there is some C++ library I don't know about that could do this, and for the sake of my own education.

Comment: [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: Also printf-style variadic - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic  also void* + a type flag variable, or a structure that bundles those together

Comment: Also `typeid.name()` is not required to return anything that will make sense to you.  Thus testing for "double" and "int" as a string is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: void* and reinterpret_cast may work for you. Use a struct which has the flag to decide the type and the data you want to pass. Bundle them together and in the function while checking the flag reinterpret_cast accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much all for the suggestions! I'll follow those links and try to get something working. And thanks for the warning PaulMcKenzie, I'll try to find an alternative.